# Facebook API Renew access token In PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have some trouble I´m new with the Facebook API... The think it´s that I need some way to renovate the user´s acccess token weekly, but user only do click on "login Facebook" button once. So the idea it´s to save the access token and weekly renew it. I found that

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/client_code?access_token=...&client_secret=...&redirect_uri=...&client_id=...
```

Give me a code and with that code I call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=...&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&machine_id= ...
```

To get the access token

But it´s throws me the old access token and not a new one... Thanks and again I'm new in that I aprecciate your answers

Comment: There is no way to “renew” a user access token without user interaction.

Comment: I read if I use this access token weekly, every time I used it I got one renovated with 60 days expiration, so the token will never expirate... It´s that true?

Comment: No, that's not true either. Using an extended token in API calls does not extend its lifetime.

Comment: Ok, so the only solution is that the user go and click the "login with Facebook" button?

Comment: If they visit a page you embed the JS SDK on while they are logged in to Facebook, that would be enough to get a fresh short-lived token.

Comment: Ok, I understand... Thanks for reply!!